# Advanced Chrome/ Chromium won't set as the default browser

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, chromium

I've downloaded Advanced Chrome (http://browser.taokaizen.com/) and am now using it instead of Chrome.

Each time I open the browser, it keeps asking me if I would like to set it as the default browser, which I do. When the browser is reopened, it asks me again. I've looked at Settings and tried to click the 'make Chromium my default browser' button, but it doesn't appear to register my wish to make it the default browser - nothing happens!

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like some kind of malwareChrome. Stay away.

Comment: Run your browser as Administrator

Answer (score -1):

It's really simple: first, install a normal latest version of Chromium. Configure it to your liking and make it the default browser. This should all work ok.

When done, download the latest zip of Advanced Chrome. Close every instance of Chromium and find the Chromium Application folder in `c:\users\(your login name)\appdata\local\Chromium`. Rename that folder for now.

Create a new Application folder in the exact same spot as the renamed one.
Unpack the contents of the folder "Advanced Chrome" inside the zip-file into your new Application folder.

Now start Chromium. You now have a working version of Advanced Chrome as your default browser.

When everything works ok, you can delete the old Application folder you renamed earlier.
Done!